# From Notification: AlertDialog without UI

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, android-intent

I'm creating a notification which fires an Intent. Here a really shortened excerpt of my code...

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(BackgroundService.this, ConnectionHandler.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, getString(R.string.notification_title), getString(R.string.notification_body), pendingIntent);
notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
nm.notify(1, notification);
```

In my intent (`ConnectionHandler.class`), I'd like to show an AlertDialog, which works. But I'd like the AlertDialog to show up without opening a new UI-Window. The best for me was if the AlertDialog simply appears without anything else when tapping the notification-entry.

Any idea is appreciated.

Regards, Tobi

Comment: thx @henrik. already late, haven't seen it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html):

> Showing a Dialog
>
> A dialog is always created and displayed as a part of an Activity.

The easy alternative is to create a very basic `Activity`, with nothing showing up except the dialog, and calling `finish()` as soon as the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: You can also give that Activity a translucent theme to keep anything but the dialog from showing up.

Comment: bah that's bad that the dialog is part of an Activity. But `finish()`ing after dismission did the trick. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create transparent Activity like below:

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

and combine it with dialog theme.

Comment: Ah... nice! I'm sure I've seen it in an application once... So it's all about styling the activity. Thanks to you, too! Maybe I'll rebuild it to this solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I think Aleadam's solution is better :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a very easy answer: the Activity **CAN** look like a dialog. In manifest add this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

And it will look like a dialog.

If you want to show up an Alert Dialog, use this code:

- Activity
  `AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Blah-Blah").setBlah().show()`
- Manifest
  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`